# Is there any way to implement a "has one of each" relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have three models with users, roles, and events. Each user can have many roles (e.g. guitarist, bassist, etc) and each role can have one or more users (e.g. Ted can act as guitarist or a bassist) who can fulfil it.

I'm creating a rota application for a church band, so it means that every event has ONE OF EACH role in the band and one user to fill each role per event. I was wondering there was any way of enforcing this relationship in the model or whether I had to do this somewhere else in the application. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: (Some bands have two guitarists.)

Comment: Yes but this application is specific to one band which will always have one of each role

Comment: I would consider putting the logic as a business rule of the DAL, not as a model rule of the ORM in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Event should have many users through EventParticipation and EventParticipation should

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

Put some [uniqueness validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) for user_id, add a role_id and do a scoped uniqueness validation if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with [custom validation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) in the model. Here's some untested code but something like

```
class ChurchEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :has_one_role_each

  def has_one_role_each
    errors.add(:base, "only one of each role allowed") if duplicate_roles?
  end

  private

  def duplicate_roles?
    # assuming band_roles is array of roles for this event
    band_roles.uniq.count != band_roles.count
  end
end
```

And something similar for the users.